# Sed Combine/Merge/Join Lines

Tags: join, sed, merge

OK I'm obviously new to this and don't know the correct format to represent my questions the best. 
I have got this code to work but I need it to work "Inplace"

As it is now it produces a 200mb file from a 16kb file.

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\nP//;ta' -e 'P;D'
```

Comment: @ Cyrus - What do I need to look at in editing?

Comment: @ Oguz Thanks for your suggestion, I have tried it and it doesn't do anything for me

Comment: @Cyrus - Could you help??